# Squid3 reverse ssl proxy SQUID_X509_V_ERR_DOMAIN_MISMATCH error

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, squid

We have squid 3.3.4 running on a Debian acting as a reverse proxy for two apache webservers with SSL pages. The traffic is being split based on the URL being received and directed to one or the other server.

```
acl acl_app urlpath_regex -i ^/app ^/store ^/admin
acl acl_old_app urlpath_regex -i ^/
acl valid_domain_acl dstdomain test.example.com

http_port 80 accel vhost
https_port 443 cert=/etc/ssl/private/example.com/current/example.com.bundle key=/etc/ssl/private/example.com/current/example.com.key  accel vhost cafile=/etc/ssl/private/example.com/current/example.com.ca-bundle

# new public site
cache_peer public.test parent 443 0 no-query no-digest originserver name=old_app ssl ssldomain=test.example.com login=PASS sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER

# new app
cache_peer app.test parent 444 0 no-query no-digest originserver name=app forceddomain=test.example.com ssl ssldomain=test.example.com login=PASS sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER

#these rules perform the following logic
#send /app traffic to app cache_peer
#send all other traffic to old_app cache_peer
cache_peer_access old_app deny acl_app
cache_peer_access old_app allow acl_old_app valid_domain_acl
cache_peer_access app allow acl_app valid_domain_acl
cache_peer_access app deny acl_old_app
```

If we put the     sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER    option in we are able to access the pages as required but if we remove the sslflags setting we receive an error SQUID_X509_V_ERR_DOMAIN_MISMATCH

The certificate on squid and on the web servers are identical and the domain names being accessed match the names in the certificate.

Although the network between squid and apache is a private network we are concerned about reducing the security on the network by effectively setting squid to ignore invalid certificates.

Any advice would be appreciated

The URLs I am using the access the site is https://www.example.com/ which should redirect to the server at public.test and https://www.example.com/app/ which should redirect to app.test

Comment: Do you have a single certificate which contains both domain names?

Comment: The certificate we have only contains www.example.com which should be sufficient. All the URLs we are accessing will be on www.example.com

Comment: But if you redirect to app.test it would expect a certificate for app.test and not for www.example.com.

Comment: This is the reason we specified the ssldomain.

Comment: It's probably just an mismatch between comment and question, but in the comment you say that the certificate is for www.example.com, while you set ssldomain to test.example.com. Apart from that I would run a tcpdump/wireshark to make sure that the certificate sent by the upstream server is really the one you expected. From what I understand squid does not use SNI, so if the upstream uses multiple certificates on the same IP it might send the wrong one back.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. The certificate and the URLs are for test.example.com. We'll give the wireshark route a bash and see if that helps. Thank you for the help.